# Display something only once in a loop in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have some pics that I want to display by months.

But I my code I get the month on top of every pics.

How to avoid this ?

```html
{% for media in medias %}
    {% if media.date|date("m") == 10 and media.assetpath is not null %}
      <h2>Photos october</h2>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset(media.assetpath)  }}"/>
        </div>
     {% elseif media.date|date("m") == 11 and media.assetpath is not null %}
       <h2>Photos november</h2>
       <div class="col-xs-2">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset(media.assetpath)  }}"/>
        </div>
    {% else %}
      <h2>other month</h2>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset(media.assetpath)  }}"/>
     </div>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Depends largely on what `medias` consists of. I think you iterate over every media and only check against a static number. I don't see any check against the current month. Have a look at `loop.first` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `medias` is an array sorted by date, the problem can be solved using a temporary variable:

```
{% set last_month = '' %}
{% for media in medias %}
  {% set month = media.date('F')|lower %}
  {% if last_month and month != last_month %}
    <h2>Photos {{ month }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {% set last_month = month %}

  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset(media.assetpath)  }}"/>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I would rather generate a more appropriate structure, e.g.:

```
$media = [
  'November' => [
    [ /* media 1 */],
    [ /* media 2 */],
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
];
```

With this structure, the template code will look much cleaner:

```
{% for month, media in medias %}
  <h2>Photos {{ month }}</h2>
  {% for m in media %}
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset(m.assetpath) }}"/>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: +1 for the second half of the answer. The problem with the first half is that you don't know how the media array is sorted, thus it could be possible you get something like `january`, `march`, `january`, ...